# redirecting when document is closed

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, redirect, file

I have Excel file eg. template.xlsx in library eg. `localhost/Documents/`. I made webpart, which creates copy of this file and display this copy (in Office WebApps) to user through hyperlink eg. `http://localhost/_layouts/xlviewer.aspx?id=/Documents/copy_template.xlsx`. I need to catch event after user close this file. It is possible to do so with event handlers, url parameters or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jiri,

You can try using Query String Source parameter, to redirect to your custom page..

Something like:

`http://localhost/_layouts/xlviewer.aspx?id=/Documents/copy_template.xlsx&Source=/Pages/CustomPage.aspx`