# Change destination URL when close Office Web Apps

Tags: office-web-apps

Can **Office Web Apps** be configured to use **specific URL** to redirect users when `WopiFrame.aspx` is closed?

By default, OWA will bring user to the document library of viewing one.

I want to make it to refer URL so that user can use both BACK and CLOSE that result in same.

I have tried following URL, but no luck.

- [sharepoint enterprise - Redirect user when document closes in office web apps? - SharePoint Stack Exchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121875/redirect-user-when-document-closes-in-office-web-apps)

Any Help will be appreciated :)

Regards,

Comment: check this one http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121875/redirect-user-when-document-closes-in-office-web-apps

Comment: I checked suggested link and tried everything there, but no change.